# Animation of UI View in table view cell is not consistent

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uianimation

For some reason, when the cell that's being animated goes off-screen and comes back, the animation speed changes. Upon tapping the cell, a new view controller is opened. After I returned from the view controller to the initial view, the animation stopped altogether.

So far, I've tried to start the animation in cellForRowAt, but that didn't seem to work either.

Link to video for the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jt5IM1Ya4gIfzb1ok-NTmS2QTnrSTNoG/view?usp=sharing

Below is the code for willDisplay cell and the functions for animating my ui view inside my table view cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = cell as? DirectionSummaryTableViewCell {
            if let isLive = cell.isLive {
                if isLive {
                    cell.animateBusStatusBackground()
                } else {
                    cell.removeAnimation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
func animateBusStatusBackground() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut], animations: { [weak self] in
            if self?.busStatusView.backgroundColor == .red {
                self?.busStatusView.backgroundColor = .grey6
            } else {
                self?.busStatusView.backgroundColor = .red
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

```
func removeAnimation() {
        self.busStatusView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DirectionSummaryTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as?  DirectionSummaryTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.configure(with: viewModel.placeToPlacePossibleDirections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].directions, 
tripDuration: viewModel.placeToPlacePossibleDirections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].tripTime,
destinationArrivalTime:viewModel.placeToPlacePossibleDirections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].reachBy,
busDepartureTime: viewModel.placeToPlacePossibleDirections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].directions.routes[0].departureTime, 
startLocation: viewModel.placeToPlacePossibleDirections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].directions.routes[0].stops[0].name, addFullLabel: true, 
isLive: viewModel.placeToPlacePossibleDirections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].responseType == "realtime")

        return cell
    }
```

```
func configure(with directions: PlaceToPlaceBusDirections, tripDuration: Double, destinationArrivalTime: String, busDepartureTime: String, startLocation: String, addFullLabel: Bool, isLive: Bool) {
        self.directions = directions
        self.isLive = isLive
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        var formattedTripDuration = ""
        if tripDuration > 60 {
            let hrs = Int(tripDuration / 60)
            formattedTripDuration += String(hrs) + " hr"
            if hrs > 1 { formattedTripDuration += "s " } else { formattedTripDuration += " " }
        }
        formattedTripDuration += String(Int(tripDuration) % 60)

        self.tripDurationLabel.text = formattedTripDuration + " mins"
        self.destinationArrivalTimeLabel.text = Date.dateStringFromString(dateString: destinationArrivalTime)
        if addFullLabel {
            self.busDeparturePlaceAndTimeLabel.text = ("Leaves at " + Date.dateStringFromString(dateString: busDepartureTime) + " from " + startLocation).maxLength(length: 40)
        } else {
            self.busDeparturePlaceAndTimeLabel.text = ("Leaves at " + Date.dateStringFromString(dateString: busDepartureTime)).maxLength(length: 40)
        }

        if !isLive {
            busStatusText.text = "Live"
            busStatusText.textColor = .white
        } else {
            busStatusText.text = "Scheduled"
            busStatusText.textColor = .grey2
            busStatusView.backgroundColor = .grey6
        }

        removeAnimation()
    }
```

How do I fix this so that the animation is the same all the time?

Comment: Remember, cells are recycled. It seems likely that some of your cells are still animating when they get dequeued. I would suggest calling your removeAnimation as soon as you fetch a cell before deciding if you need to add a new animation. Also, I would not call layoutIfNeeded in your `removeAnimation()` method.

Comment: Adding to what @DuncanC said, as far as the animation speed difference is concerned, you're doing something else wrong somewhere. With the code above used in a straightforward sample, the animation works as expected.  One thing to note in your video is that, in the initial part of the video where the cells blink really fast, that is the animation which does not match with the code you shared above. When you scroll the table view and new cells come into view and show the slow animation, that is the correct animation with a 1 second duration (by correct I mean the one that matches the code)

Comment: Removed self.layoutIfNeeded() and called remove animation before deciding to add a new animation, but the problem persists.

Comment: So it seems like something else might be going on when the cells are initialised. Now, regarding going to a different screen and coming back, in your viewWillAppear(:), you'll have to notify all [visible cells](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells) in your table view that they should start animating.

Comment: that's a good point @AmanShankarSharma, ill look into why its animating so much faster in the start

Comment: thanks, ill add that for the viewWillAppear(:)

Comment: I've also added an answer showing how you can animate cells when you return from a different screen that you navigate to, you should obviously refactor / tailor it to suit your implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251838/discussion-between-aman-shankar-sharma-and-sahil-sahu).

Answer (score 1):

To animate cells when you return from a different screen you can use something like below:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    if let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells as? [DirectionSummaryTableViewCell] {
        visibleCells.forEach {
            if let isLive = $0.isLive {
                if isLive {
                    $0.animateBusStatusBackground()
                } else {
                    $0.removeAnimation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. When the view controller first appears, visibleCells will be empty, so the code won't do anything. If the VC gets covered by a modal and then revealed, only the visible cells will be updated. (Voted)